# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: won't accept my custom UIImageView pointers, why not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, performselector

Okay guys...
Hopefully this will be another quickie.

I have a class MonsterView, extending UIImageView, extending NSObject.

I have declared a MonsterView pointer called myMonster that contains an object of class MonsterView and looks something like this...

```
MonsterView* myMonster = [monsterArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now the pointer myMonster points to an object of class MonsterView.

I have a method like:

```
-(void) takeTurnHostile:(MonsterView*) monster
{
     // Do Stuff
}
```

I want to call this method by using performSelector...
Like THIS:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(takeTurnHostile) withObject:myMonster afterDelay:0.1];
```

The bloody machine will not have any such nonsense.
Why in the name of all that is good and holy can't I do this?

More importantly, how -COULD- I do this?

Thanks, guys!
J-Rock

Comment: Umm...  Thanks, I guess.  Was it really necessary to D-List my reputation for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@selector(takeTurnHostile)
```

should be

```
@selector(takeTurnHostile:)
```

because your selector takes an argument, and the colon is part of the selector name.

Answer (score 1):

Missing colon in the selector...

```
[self performSelector:@selector(takeTurnHostile:) withObject:myMonster afterDelay:0.1];
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be `@selector(takeTurnHostile:)`. You've forgot the colon

Answer (score 1):

As H2CO3 said you must provide the colon:

```
takeTurnHostile:
```

The colon indicates that the method you are calling has 1 parameter. Currently without the colon you are saying to run the method:

```
-(void) takeTurnHostile
{
}
```